# Expected time of last bus left

Tags: probability

I came across the following problem in a probability exercise, and got confused. The problem is the following.

**Problem**: In a bus station, assume the expected time of next bus arriving is a exponential distribution $Exp(\lambda)$, where $\lambda$=0.1/min, and you arrive at the bus station in a uniform random time. Let $X$ be the amount of time that last bus has left before you arrive. What is $E(X)$?

I applied some probability properties, and got answer 0, which is obviously wrong. Could you please help me see where I am wrong? It would be even better if you could give me a correct solution. Thanks!

**My solution**: Assume starting at time 0, the buses arrive at time $X_1, X_2, \cdots$, and the interval between buses are $Z_1, Z_2, \cdots$, where $Z_i=X_{i}-X_{i-1}$. Then $Z_i \sim Exp(\lambda)$. Assume the person arrives at the station at time $Y$, and assume $X_k \leq Y < X_{k+1}$. Then 
$$X=Y-X_k=Y-\sum_{i=1}^k Z_i.$$
Fix $Y$ and $k$, we have
$$E(X)=Y-k E(Z_1) = Y-k\frac{1}{\lambda}.$$
Fix $Y$, the number $k$ is the number of events between $[0, Y]$, and satisfies a Poisson  distribution with parameter $\lambda$. Thus 
$$E(k)=\lambda Y.$$
Therefore we have 
$$E(X)=Y-\lambda Y \frac{1}{\lambda}=0.$$

Answer (score 1):

One cannot *arrive at the bus station [at] a uniform random time* because there is no uniform distribution on the positive real halfline hence the problem is ill posed.

The correct version of the problem is called the *waiting time paradox*, and asks about the limit of the expected time since the last bus left if one arrives at time $y$, when $y\to\infty$. The expected time since the last bus left if one arrives at time $y$ is $\frac1\lambda(1-\mathrm e^{-\lambda y})$ hence the limit when $y\to\infty$ is $\frac1\lambda$. See [here](http://mahalanobis.twoday.net/stories/3486587/) for some more detailed explanations.

Answer (score -1):

The most important thing about $Y$ is $X_k \le Y \lt X_{k+1}$.  Anything which happened before $X_k$ is irrelevant.

The obvious answer is that the expected time since the last bus is the expected time to the next bus, i.e. 10 minutes.

Let's prove this looking forward: the exponential distribution is memoryless, so knowing $X_k \le Y \lt X_{k+1}$ you find $\Pr(X_{k+1}-Y=x)=1 − e^{−\lambda x}$, leading to $E[X_{k+1}-Y] = 1/\lambda$.

Going backwards, you may decide the distribution is the similar by symmetry. Alternatively

Comment: Hmmm... The residual waiting time at time $t$ and the time since the last bus before $t$ are **NOT** equidistributed, except in the limit $t\to\infty$.

Comment: Why not, assuming that at least one bus has arrived before $t$? It is reasonable to state that you arrive at a time uniformly (and so symmetrically) distributed between the times of the two buses you arrive between, so $\Pr(Y-X_k \le x) = \Pr(X_{k+1}-Y \le x)$

Comment: Well, for one thing, the residual waiting time may be as large as one wants while the time since the last bus arrived is at most $t$. (You know, all this is really textbook matter...)

Comment: @Didier: I don't accept that: you seem to be presuming that the buses will run eternally into the future but have only been running since for a finite time. You are saying you have probably arrived closer to the last bus than to the next bus; I would suggest that the question suggests otherwise: "uniformly random time" must mean uniformly between buses if it is to mean anything, so the assumption should be that buses both will run and have been running eternally.

Comment: ... or at least that there will be sufficient time for the next bus and there has been sufficient time for the last bus, and these conditions are symmetric.

Comment: Did you notice the (rigorous) explanation in my answer and in the link I provided? By the way: you seem to know what "uniformly random time" means, please share your insights.

Comment: @Didier: I take uniformly random time to mean $\Pr(Y\le a+p(b-a)|X_k=a, X_{k+1}=b, X_k\le Y \lt X_{k+1})=p$.  I don't see $t$ as having to be non-negative: things may have happened yesterday.

Comment: What would be the distribution of a random variable $Y$ satisfying this for every $a$, $b>a$, $p$ in $(0,1)$, and $k$?