# Last hit before random time s in Poisson point process - expected value.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, expectation, stopping-times

I'm stuck computing the expected value of the last hitting time before a time $s$ in the waiting time paradoxon. Suppose we come to a bus stop at a time $s \in \mathbb{R}$, where buses are randomly stopping according to a Poisson process with intensity $\gamma$. With $\tau_s$ we denote the time, the last bus before $s$ has left. The distribution is

$\mathbb{P}_{\tau_s} = \mathbb{P}_{s-X}$ where $X\sim Expo(\gamma)$. I want to compute the expected value of $\tau_s$, which should be $s-\frac{1}{\gamma}(1-e^{-\gamma s})$, as in @Did's answer in this post: [Expected time of last bus left](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80347/expected-time-of-last-bus-left)

Since my attempts don't output this well-known formula, there must be some mistake, which I fail to see:

$\mathbb{E}[\tau_s] = \int_\Omega \tau_s(\omega)dP(\omega) = \int_\Omega s-X(\omega)dP(\omega) = s-\int_\Omega 1_{(X(\omega)\leq s)}X(\omega)dP(\omega) = s- \mathbb{E}[X, X\leq s] = s-\int_0^s  x\cdot f_X(x) dx = s-\int_0^s x\gamma e^{-\gamma x} = s-\frac{1}{\gamma}(1-e^{-\gamma s})+se^{-\gamma s}$

Please, where is my mistake?

Comment: What is $\tau_s$ if no bus left between times $0$ and $s$?

Comment: Good question... The supremum of the empty set. So, I suppose, $-\infty$...

Comment: Then the expectation does not exist. Note also that, if, as in your computations, $\tau_s=s-X$ with $X$ exponential, then the support of the distribution of $\tau_s$ is $(-\infty,s]$... All this does not add up, please clarify.

Comment: Hum. The definition I have is just this: $\tau_s := sup\{\tau_n\mid n\geq 0, \tau_n\leq s\}$ where $\tau_n$ is the nth hitting time/arrival time. My paper goes on to state the formula I am trying to verify for the expectation of $\tau_s$. I took $(0, s)$ as support, because $\tau_s$ makes sense only if it is positive. But perhaps I should define $\tau_s$ to be zero, if there hasn't been any bus before the time s?

Comment: Well, I just see, that $\tau_0 = 0$. Maybe that helps. I will try to verify...

Comment: Indeed, if $\tau_0=0$, your $\tau_s$ is $s-\min\{X,s\}$ where $X$ is exponential--then you need to revise your computations, but, if you do, the correct formula should pop up.

Comment: Alright, it popped up... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some help from the comments, I was able to solve the question:

Since $\tau_s$ cannot be negative-valued, its distribution is really $\tau_s \sim (s-\min\{X, s\})$ with $x\sim Expo(\gamma)$. Thus

$\mathbb{E}[\tau_s] = \mathbb{E}[s-\min\{X, s\}] = \mathbb{E}[s-X, X< s]$ since if $X\geq s$ then $s-\min\{X, s\} = s- s = 0$.

$\mathbb{E}[s-X, X< s] = \mathbb{P}[X<s]\cdot s - \mathbb{E}[X, X< s] = (1-e^{-\gamma s})s - \int_0^s x\gamma e^{-\gamma x}dx$

hence

$\mathbb{E}[s-X, X< s] = (1-e^{-\gamma s})s-\frac{1}{\gamma}(1-e^{-\gamma s})+se^{-\gamma s} = s- \frac{1}{\gamma}(1-e^{-\gamma s})$

as desired.

Comment: Nicely done, +1.